# MAUI Blazor App - cant find Windows Machine in Debug List

Tags: blazor, maui

I have a basic MAUI Blazor app (counter app).  When I went to debug this app it would load in a Windows Machine mode in the dropdown list.  But after upgrading VS 2022 to latest version - this option has disappeared from the Debug dropdown list.  See below the option im after - but it seems to have disapeared and im not sure how i get this back.  Does anybody else have this option?

TIA

[image]

I created a new MAUI Blazor app and I get the below.
[image]

I also had VS 2022 Community edirion installed on my PC - so I thought I woudl give it a try and it doesnt seem to like one line.  See below:

[image]

Comment: Probably something inconsistent in information Visual Studio maintains for your solution. Delete hidden `.vs` folder and delete all `.bin` and `.obj` folders. OR download your sources from your source repository, to a new, empty folder.

Comment: hi, I created a new MAUI Blazor server app (Counter app).  In this ap i get the Windows Machine option in the Debug dropdown list - but when I click Debug teh buidl starts but the Windows Machine emulator never starts up.  See attached screen shot. TIA

Comment: Its as if it ran, but immediately exited. Something seems to have gone wrong in the VS Update. I would delete Visual Studio, reboot pc, install Visual Studio again.

Comment: Probably better not to split the discussion across two posts. You asked the same question at [Cannot find emulator for MAUI Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813030/cannot-find-emulator-for-maui-blazor)

BTW: you're trying to build a Windows app, and Windows apps run directly on Windows. There's no emulator involved. That's just nitpicking and doesn't explain why you can't successfully build & run the Windows app.

Comment: Rob - sorry for the duplicate post.  Im ever so sorry

@ToolmakerSteve - see attached screen shot - I also had VS 2022 Community Edition installed and this seems to throw an error when I try and debug.  Any idea what this line does?   Could it be the underlying issue. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding "Windows Machine" not working, I have the same problem.  See that answer that was provided:  [.NET 7 Blazor MAUI "Windows Machine" will not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064353/net-7-blazor-maui-windows-machine-will-not-run/75064499#75064499)

Regarding the GetLatestMSVCVersion error, it is occurring because a VC folder is probably missing.  There should be 2 folders in: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022(Community/Professional)\VC": "\Redist\MSVC" and "\Tools\MSVC".  To restore the folder, do a Repair on your Visual Studio installation.

Regarding not being able to delete the solution folder, that is because a process has the folder locked.  Rather than reinstalling VS, use the Resource Monitor to find the processes and kill them.  Close Visual Studio, open Resource Monitor (Click Windows-key, type "Resource Monitor", Enter). Select the CPU tab, then in the Associated Handles window, search for the solution name.  Select the appropriate Image, then right-click/End Process.  As an alternative to using this method, you can install the "Handle" application:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Comment: OMG you are a star!!!  That worked..... I have spent ages on this and installing the fix on thsi post that did teh trick

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080#issuecomment-1358398569

Im forever greatful... I have been pulling my hair out with this one for a while

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure the `launchsettings.json` file is in the Properties folder.