# .NET 7 Blazor MAUI "Windows Machine" will not run

Tags: maui-blazor

I created a default .NET 7 Blazor MAUI solution. The Android emulator works properly, but the "Windows Machine" Framework (net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0) does not start.

The only message is "The program 'xxxx' has exited with code 2147942405 (0x80070005)." I have set a breakpoint in the Program.cs file, but the breakpoint is never reached. The Build and Deployment output windows don't show any errors.

maui-check does not show any issues. I've tried deleting the .vs, bin, and obj folders. My system is running Windows 10 Pro 22H2, .NET 7.0.101 SDK, and 7.0.1 runtimes, with VS2022 17.4.3

Any ideas on how to get this to start?

Comment: Did you try the workaround in the link I provided?

Comment: I went to the link you sent and was reading through the Issue.  I was about ready to do the fix but got side-tracked.  I do not understand how it happened, but the issue is now resolved.  The only change I made was to Repair my Visual Studio install to fix another problem.  After that the "Windows Machine" works.  To verify it wasn't a 'fluke', I have created several new solutions and they all work.  This morning I upgraded VS to 17.4.4 and adding new solutions continue to work.  I passed the link you provided to another user, and it solved their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an existed issue which is about [MAUI apps crash on launch on Windows after Visual Studio update - code 2147942405](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080) on the github.

And you can try the workaround in this issue which tried to [download the Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Redist.1.2.zip and run its WindowsAppRuntimeInstall.exe (as admin)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080#issuecomment-1358398569) .

You can also follow up this issue on the github and wait for fixing this bug.